# My 3-year old baby girl has been holding in her poop since she was young. What can I do?

Tags: family-planning

Her poop problem worries me too much. I do not know what to do, or how to start and look for what might help her. My baby is in pain. This is so sad watching her holding, and sometimes I beat her.

Comment: Hi and welcome. I don't think there are any studies that show beating her will help. Although you are an adult, if you were, say, allergic to milk, would beating you help? It's kind of the same situation with your girl. For some reason, her body doesn't feel the urge to poop as it should. I would, as @Jeff.Clark suggested, start with stool softeners and lots of liquids, and read some of the questions here with the tag *encopresis*.

Comment: I have been known to spank my children.  It is extremely rare and only when they do something that is clearly morally wrong, and even then most of the times I look for any other way I can make sure they get the message that what they did is wrong.  Not wanting to go to the toilet is not something that merits spanking, much less anything that can be described as "beating", which sounds really bad.  There is some negative feeling, probably fear, about going to the toilet, and your beating her will only make the whole experience even more fearful for her.

Comment: You need to talk to a doctor about this. This is a medical problem with a number of possible causes, and we can't diagnose over the internet. And please stop beating your daughter.

Answer (score 3):

My 5 year old used to do that when he was 3 or 4. He had some really painful bowl movements for a couple days from something (cheese/not enough water?), and after that was really scared to go. Which, of course, made it even more painful because of holding it in. He did this for quite a while. We ended up giving him some stool softener for a few months so he could get it through his head that it really didn't hurt most of the time.